# how to solve this error aapt.exe

Tags: android, debugging, android-gradle-plugin

Please help me what is error I did everything I could  but as before

```
\Project\TEST\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\drawable-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png: Original is here. The version qualifier may be implied.


\Project\TEST\\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\ic_launcher.png: error: Duplicate file.
```

I'm try delete ic_launcher.png from intermediates\res\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4 and clean and rebuild but as before

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'F:\Deverloper\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to move the ic_launcher in mipmap-... folders?

If not try to create mipmap forlders for all the resolutions and move the ic_launcher.png files into them (make sure they are removed from drawable folders.

Also don't forget to change the reference in the android manifest file :-)